# Java Regex jumps to next match with if clause

Tags: java, regex, if-statement

I have this source:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "Real bad day today XY= '5678' XY='345' yes really AYB='3456' and maybe also SA='87565' or maybe this AS = '9867' or maybe even not";
        final String regex = "XY\\s*=\\s*'\\d+'";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);

        System.out.println(matcher.find());

        if (matcher.find()) {

            System.out.println(matcher.group());

            String newstring=matcher.group().replaceAll("'", "");
            System.out.println(newstring);

            String finalstring=EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(matcher.group(), newstring);
            System.out.println("ENDE:" + finalstring);
        }

    }
}
```

Without the if clause it replaces XY= '5678' with XY= 5678 and all is well, with the if clause it replaces XY='345' with XY=345. But it should only replace the one it first finds.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using `matcher.find()` twice. Remove the first one, `System.out.println(matcher.find());`.

Comment: ok thanks.. really not my day today.